# How to logged all message from telegram bot?

Tags: c#, logging, telegram, telegram-bot

I have Telegram-bot, which send messages to all users, which have conversation channel with it.

How i can get all this bot's messages? Does it have some log functionality? Or on C# API can I create it?

Comment: Do you mean messages which the bot has sent? Or messages which have been sent to the bot.

Comment: @Mark i mean messages which the bot has sent to every user

Comment: I would keep track of those by putting them in some sort of SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Bot API doesn't provide a way of fetching the chat history, you get every update only once.

You will have to save messages as they come in, probably in a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have all messages, received by bot, the simplest way to store all bot's message without the need for databases, files, etc - is to [forward](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage) all messages received by bot to your personal account or to group chat.

Example:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    // do something with msg here
    bot.forwardMessage(process.env.DEVELOPER_CHAT_ID, msg.chat.id, msg.message_id);
})
```